# WWW fails to download a file on iOS [Unity]

Tags: ios, xcode, file, unity-game-engine, download

I'm making a fortnite-guide app where it shows the battle pass quests & some tips, everything is stored in a json file, so I basically want to download that son file to load the data...
Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GetData : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GetData Instance = null;

    private List<Weeks> publicWeeks = new List<Weeks>();
    private bool dataLoaded = false;
    private string errorText;

    public string ErrorText {
        get { return errorText; }
    }

    public List<Weeks> PublicWeeks {
        get { return publicWeeks; }
    }

    public bool DataLoaded {
        get { return dataLoaded; }
    }

    void Awake() {
        if(Instance == null)
            Instance = this;
        else if(Instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Start () 
    {
        string url = "https://d7coins.com/fgdata.json";
           WWW www = new WWW(url);
           StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
   }

    string fixJson(string value) {
        value = "{\"Items\":" + value + "}";
        return value;
    }

  IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www) {
      yield return www;

      // check for errors
      if (www.error == null)
      {
          string jsonString = fixJson(www.text);
          Weeks[] weeksArray = JsonHelper.FromJson<Weeks>(jsonString);

          for(int i = 0; i < weeksArray.Length; i++) {
              publicWeeks.Add(weeksArray[i]);
          }

          dataLoaded = true;
      } else {
          dataLoaded = false;
          errorText = ("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
      } 
  }

}

[Serializable]
    public class Weeks {
        public int week;
        public string quest;
        public string tips;
    }
```

It works fine when I run it in Unity itself, but running it on an iDevice fails to download the file for some reason...

Here's the Xcode log:
https://pastebin.com/D8ei4MMi

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you know it fails to download? Do you get any error?

Comment: @Programmer because it's supposed to show me the data in the app, but it doesn't...

Comment: Waht do you see in the debugger's local vars windos at `if (www.error == null)`?

Comment: You can see the returned JSON in the Xcode log so you are receiving it something else is going wrong, this is also outside the scope of what you asked but a webpage is much better suited to this, it already works on every platform with a browser, it's easier to set up and maintain. I can provide a webpage example if you would like.

Comment: iOS can block insecure requests. I don't know exactly the policy, but try to change your url to `"https://d7coins.com/fgdata.json"` Your certificate appears to be valid.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 I'm making this app for someone else, it has to be an app...

Comment: @dome12b it's already "https://d7coins.com/fgdata.json", I've just forgot to edit it...

Comment: Add `while(!www.isDone){Debug.Log("Downloading")}` before your `yield return www;` and see if that works

Comment: @Hristo I get this error "[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert"

Comment: Even with that error, I'm pretty sure your file is getting downloaded. Could you try logging your downloaded text. Or you could make a text object in Unity and set its text equal to the downloaded text.

Comment: That's what I'm making @Hristo, but the text object never changes on device, although it changes when I play it in Unity...

Comment: Kind of a dumb question, but do you have active internet connection on your device?

Comment: @Hristo Yep, I do.